# How to do a wsdl Request-response with soap in php?

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

So I'm really stuck now. I'm new to soap and WSDL. I know some Oop Java and some Oop Php. I trying to call functions in a Java WSDL API. Methods that dont require any params works fine and returns values. But when I'm trying to send params to methods that require params it only throws exceptions. Im using php > 5.4. This is my third day I'm trying to figure this out without any luck.
The provider of the API dosen't have any technical personel for my assistence and I'm stuck with endless documentation of their system.

I need to fetch a persons all check-ins the past week in the system, based on a hunch I choose this API endpoint (BookingAPI)

```
$allEndpoints = [AccessAPI, AccountReceivableAPI, BookingAPI, ChildCareAPI, CompanyAPI, CrmAPI, ExtractAPI, GiftCardAPI, PersonAPI, PrivilegeAPI, ProductAPI, QuestionnaireAPI, ResourceBookingAPI, SelfServiceAPI, StaffBookingAPI, StaffBookingAPI, SubscriptionAPI, TestAPI]
```

But for simplification for this qusetion I have chosen a function with fewer params.

Some code:

```
echo "<pre style=\"display:block;word-wrap: break-word;\">";

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
        "login" => $login,
        "password" => $password,
        "trace" => 1,
        "exceptions" => 0)
    );


// TRY DIFFERENT OBJECTIFICATIONS HERE; SEE BELOW


print "Client : \n";
var_dump($client);
print "<br>Functions : \n";
// var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
print "<br>Types : \n";
// var_dump($client->__getTypes());
// print "<br />\n Request : ".htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest());
// print "<br />\n Response: ".htmlspecialchars(utf8_decode($client->__getLastResponse()));

print "<br>Values : \n";
print_r($value);
```

Following some tuts and some SO threads I have tried the following:

When I'm trying:

```
$myClass->token = new \stdClass;
$myClass->personId = '6204';
$value = $client->getDetails($myClass);
```

I get:

> ```
> Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /path/to/dist/index.php on line 143
> Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'center' property in /path/to/dist/index.php on line 145
> ```

If I try:

```
$myParam = new SoapParam("6204", "PersonKey");
$value = $client->getDetails($myParam);
```

I get:

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => dk.procard.eclub.api.v4.exceptions.APIException: dk.procard.eclub.api.exceptions.ImplException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown center
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /path/to/dist/index.php
    [line:protected] => 154
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /path/to/dist/index.php
                    [line] => 154
                    [function] => __call
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => getDetails
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => SoapParam Object
                                        (
                                            [param_name] => PersonKey
                                            [param_data] => 6204
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /path/to/dist/index.php
                    [line] => 154
                    [function] => getDetails
                    [class] => SoapClient
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SoapParam Object
                                (
                                    [param_name] => PersonKey
                                    [param_data] => 6204
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [faultstring] => dk.procard.eclub.api.v4.exceptions.APIException: dk.procard.eclub.api.exceptions.ImplException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown center
    [faultcode] => env:Server
    [detail] => stdClass Object
        (
            [APIException] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [errorCode] => ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT
                    [errorMessage] => dk.procard.eclub.api.exceptions.ImplException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown center
                    [message] => dk.procard.eclub.api.v4.exceptions.APIException: dk.procard.eclub.api.exceptions.ImplException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown center
                )
        )
)
```

From the documentation:

> Person getDetails(PersonKey personId)     throws APIException
>
> ```
> Gets the details for a person.
> ```
>
> Parameters:
>
> personId - Required. The id of the person for which the details should be returned
>
> Returns:
>
> the details of the person
>
> Throws:   APIException - Will only throw
>
> general error codes.
>
> See Also:     blabla

How can I do a requset with desired response? All help and pointers are greatly appreciated, thank you!

[EDIT]

Follow up question:

How can i send a "id"-parameter in my request?
findPersons( arg0->attributes->id );

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v4="path/to/api?wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <v4:findPersons>
         <arg0>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <attributes>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <id>?</id>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <value>?</value>
            </attributes>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <birthday>?</birthday>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <center>?</center>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <country>?</country>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <name>?</name>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <personType>?</personType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <phoneNumber>?</phoneNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <socialSecurityNumber>?</socialSecurityNumber>
         </arg0>
      </v4:findPersons>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

for your first approach:

```
$myClass = new \stdClass;
$myClass->personId = 6204;
$value = $client->getDetails(array($myParam));
```

2nd approach:

```
$myParam = new SoapVar("6204", XSD_STRING); // it should be the same type of personId at wsdl
$value = $client->getDetails(array('personId' => $myParam));
```

Comment: I keep getting this message "Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'center' property in /dist/index.php on line 154"

Comment: at this point your params is not fitting the wsdl you need to fulfil wsdl requierments headers authentication some other params etc. seems like method is seeking another parameter named "center"

Comment: Is there a way to find out which params and headers are required to make a certain api call?

Comment: Yes, open your browser and take a look at your wsdl url or you can use free application SoapUI. 
Warning sometimes soap-server side making an IP restriction so be aware of it.